# Invalid Stripe API version: [object Object] when connecting to stripe api

Tags: typescript, aws-lambda, stripe-payments

Am trying to send a post request to stripe api to create a new customer. But stripe keeps returning Invalid Stripe API version - even though I've got the latest version recommended from them.

Below is my code:

```
import Stripe from 'stripe';
import { APIGatewayEvent, Callback, Context, Handler } from 'aws-lambda';


const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_....' || '', {
  apiVersion: "2020-08-27",
});
 

interface ICreateCustomer {
  // stripeToken: string;
  email: string;
  username: string;
}

export const respond = (fulfillmentText: any): any => {
  return {
    statusCode: 200,
    body: JSON.stringify(fulfillmentText),
    headers: {
      "Access-Control-Allow-Credentials": true,
      "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*",
      "Content-Type": "application/json"
    }
  };
};

export const createCustomer: Handler = async (
  event: APIGatewayEvent,
  context: Context
) => {
  const incoming: ICreateCustomer = JSON.parse(event.body);
  const { email, username } = incoming;
  try {

    //Create Stripe Customer 
    const customer = await stripe.customers.create({
              email,
              name: username,
            });
    
    return respond(JSON.stringify(customer));
  } catch (err) {
    return respond(err);
  }
};
```

Comment: Strange... the code regarding the Stripe API version looks fine to me.  If you omit the `apiVersion` portion all together and do `const stripe = new Stripe('sk_test_....');` instead what happens?

Comment: It throws an error: An argument for 'config' was not provided

Comment: This is what it needs up referencing constructor(apiKey: string, config: Stripe.StripeConfig);

Comment: I think I managed to find a possible fix - I removed a plugin which was in the serverless.yml file. The plugin I removed was - serverless-webpack

Answer (score 0):

this solution work for me

1. **delete node_module and package-lock.json file**
2. **npm install**

refer this for more details https://github.com/stripe/stripe-node/blob/master/examples/webhook-signing/typescript-node-express/express-ts.ts